# why cerr flushes the buffer of cout

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;
#include <cstdio>

int   main( )
{
    char pbuffer[BUFSIZ];
    setbuf(stdout, pbuffer);
    cout << "hello cout" ;
    sleep(5);
    cerr << "hello cerr";
    sleep(5);
    cout << "\nAll   done " << endl;
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

after I compile and run the program above, it's output is :

```
hello couthello cerr
All   done
```

but I think it should be:

```
hello cerrhello cout
All   done
```

I want to know, why `cerr` flushes the buffer of `cout` ?

Comment: `cout << "hello cout";` comes before `cerr << "hello cerr";`

Comment: I want to know why the output of cout comes before cerr. I think the output of cout is buffered, the output of cerr should come out first

Answer (score 12):

This is by design.

Both `cin` and `cerr` are tied to `cout`, and calls cout.flush() before any of their own operations.

The idea is probably that input and output should occur in a proper order.

Comment: This is wrong.  `cout` is tied to `cin`, but that's all.  `cerr` isn't tied to anything, and has nothing tied to it.  (That doesn't mean that the implementation isn't using other synchronization mechanisms.  But `cerr.tie()` is required to return a null pointer.)

Comment: A quick check shows that VC8 has an error here: `cerr.tie()` does return non-null, even though this is explicitly forbidden by the C++ standard.  (g++ gets it right.)

Comment: @James - In my copy of the draft is says "After the object cerr is initialized, `cerr.flags() & unitbuf` is nonzero and `cerr.tie()` returns `&cout`." (27.4.2)

Comment: I'm looking at the actual ISO C++ 2003 standard, which says "After the object cerr is initialized, cerr.flags() & unitbuf is nonzero. Its state is otherwise the same as required for `basic_ios<char>::init.", which requires `tie() == 0`.  I see that later drafts have changed this---yet another incompatibility to deal with.  (Not a serious one, however, since as far as I can see, `cout` and `cerr` could actually share the same `streambuf`, which synchronizes even more.)

Comment: `cerr` is _now_ tied to `cout` - citing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cerr - In addition, `std::cerr.tie()` returns `&std::cout` (same for` wcerr` and `std::wcout`), meaning that any output operation on `std::cerr` first executes `std::cout.flush()` (via `std::basic_ostream::sentry`'s constructor) (since C++11).

Comment: For historical interests: the request of the behavior change to make `cerr` tie to `cout` was once rejected by the committee in [LWG 178](https://wg21.link/lwg178), but later [WG21 N1569](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1569.htm) pointed out it should be changed. Then came [LWG 455](https://wg21.link/lwg455). Finally the fix was adopted [in the working paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1805.html) in 2005.

Answer (score 11):

First, a stream is allowed to flush whenever it feels like it.  I possible that some implementations of iostream do change buffering policies when outputting to an interactive device.  Unless you intentionally flush between outputs on the two streams, the order they appear is more or less unspecified; all you can count on is that a single `<<` to `cerr` will not have characters from `cout` inserted into it.  In your case, the implementation is synchronizing `cout` and `cerr` in some way.  (You might want to see what happens if you redirect their output to different files.  Or to the same non-interactive file—C++ makes no distinction between interactive devices and others, but C does, and I expect that most C++ implementations follow C in this respect.)

FWIW, the two guarantees concerning order are:

- `cout` is tied to `cin`, so any attempt to read on `cin` will flush `cout`, and
- `cerr` has `unitbuf` set, so it will be flushed at the end of every `<<` operator.

The idea behind the latter is, I think, to obtain something similar to C's line buffering, which C++ doesn't support directly—although if you use `std::endl`, you get the same effect as line buffering.