# iostream thread safety, must cout and cerr be locked separately?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, cout

I understand that to avoid output intermixing access to cout and cerr by multiple threads must be synchronized. In a program that uses both cout and cerr, is it sufficient to lock them separately? or is it still unsafe to write to cout and cerr simultaneously?

Edit clarification: I understand that cout and cerr are "Thread Safe" in C++11. My question is whether or not a write to cout and a write to cerr by different threads simultaneously can interfere with each other (resulting in interleaved input and such) in the way that two writes to cout can.

Comment: It's never "unsafe". You may just not get what you expect.

Comment: I guess to clarify then. Is there a difference in behavior between using one global lock for writes to both cout and cerr vs a separate lock for each?

Comment: you can use different locks.  they don't depend on each other.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better phrased as, "*May* cout and cerr be locked separately?"

Comment: Also see [Is cout synchronized/thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374264/608639)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you execute this function:

```
void f() {
    std::cout << "Hello, " << "world!\n";
}
```

from multiple threads you'll get a more-or-less random interleaving of the two strings, `"Hello, "` and `"world\n"`. That's because there are two function calls, just as if you had written the code like this:

```
void f() {
    std::cout << "Hello, ";
    std::cout << "world!\n";
}
```

To prevent that interleaving, you have to add a lock:

```
std::mutex mtx;
void f() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << "world!\n";
}
```

That is, the problem of interleaving has **nothing to do** with `cout`. It's about the code that uses it: there are two separate function calls inserting text, so unless you prevent multiple threads from executing the same code at the same time, there's a potential for a thread switch between the function calls, which is what gives you the interleaving.

Note that a mutex **does not** prevent thread switches. In the preceding code snippet, it prevents **executing** the contents of `f()` simultaneously from two threads; one of the threads has to wait until the other finishes.

If you're **also** writing to `cerr`, you have the same issue, and you'll get interleaved output unless you ensure that you never have two threads making these inserter function calls at the same time, and that means that both functions must use the same mutex:

```
std::mutex mtx;
void f() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << "world!\n";
}

void g() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    std::cerr << "Hello, " << "world!\n";
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that if the OS directs both `cout` and `cerr` to the same source (like... the console), then the text will be interleaved, unless they share the same mutex.

Comment: The OS and libraries have a lot to do with it. Threads in Linux can output to stdout all they like, no locking, yet individual lines of text will not get scrambled by another thread's stdout. Output to stderr is not buffered in the same way, so it will get scambled up. This difference in behaviour causes problems in some versions of Eclipse CDT; compiler errors come out on stderr and do not appear in the right place wrt the stdout from the compiler in Eclipse's console.

Answer (score 9):

In C++11, unlike in C++03, the insertion to and extraction from global stream objects (`cout`, `cin`, `cerr`, and `clog`) are **thread-safe**. There is no need to provide manual synchronization. It is possible, however, that characters inserted by different threads will interleave unpredictably while being output; similarly, when multiple threads are reading from the standard input, it is unpredictable which thread will read which token.

Thread-safety of the global stream objects is active by default, but it can be turned off by invoking the `sync_with_stdio` member function of the stream object and passing `false` as an argument. In that case, you would have to handle the synchronization manually.

Answer (score 5):

It **may** be unsafe to write to cout and cerr simultaneously !
It depends on wheter cout is *tied* to cerr or not. See [std::ios::tie](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/).

> "The tied stream is an output stream object which is flushed before
>   each i/o operation in this stream object."

This means, that cout.flush() may get called unintentionally by the thread which writes to cerr.
I spent some time to figure out, that this was the reason for randomly missing line endings in cout's output in one of my projects :(

With C++98 cout should not be tied to cerr. But despite the standard it is tied when using MSVC 2008  (my experience). When using the following code everything works well.

```
std::ostream *cerr_tied_to = cerr.tie();
if (cerr_tied_to) {
    if (cerr_tied_to == &cout) {
        cerr << "DBG: cerr is tied to cout ! -- untying ..." << endl;
        cerr.tie(0);
    }
}
```

See also: [why cerr flushes the buffer of cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027034/why-cerr-flushes-the-buffer-of-cout)

Comment: Interesting. To be sure, this isn't unsafe as UB, it's "only" behaving badly.

Comment: Wow... this caused me some hard to spot bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There are already several answers here. I'll summarize and also address interactions between them.

### Typically,

`std::cout` and `std::cerr` will often be funneled into a single stream of text, so locking them in common results in the most usable program.

If you ignore the issue, `cout` and `cerr` by default alias their `stdio` counterparts, which are thread-safe [as in POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467938/stdout-thread-safe-in-c-on-linux/), up to the standard I/O functions (C++14 §27.4.1/4, a stronger guarantee than C alone). If you stick to this selection of functions, you get garbage I/O, but not undefined behavior (which is what a language lawyer might associate with "thread safety," irrespective of usefulness).

However, note that while standard formatted I/O functions (such as reading and writing numbers) are thread-safe, the manipulators to change the format (such as `std::hex` for hexadecimal or `std::setw` for limiting an input string size) are not. So, one can't generally assume that omitting locks is safe at all.

If you choose to lock them separately, things are more complicated.

### Separate locking

For performance, lock contention may be reduced by locking `cout` and `cerr` separately. They're separately buffered (or unbuffered), and they may flush to separate files.

By default, `cerr` flushes `cout` before each operation, because they are "tied." This would defeat both separation and locking, so remember to call `cerr.tie( nullptr )` before doing anything with it. (The same applies to `cin`, but not to `clog`.)

### Decoupling from `stdio`

The standard says that operations on `cout` and `cerr` do not introduce races, but that can't be exactly what it means. The stream objects aren't special; their underlying `streambuf` buffers are.

Moreover, the call `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio` is intended to remove the special aspects of the standard streams — to allow them to be buffered as other streams are. Although the standard doesn't mention any impact of `sync_with_stdio` on data races, a quick look inside the libstdc++ and libc++ (GCC and Clang) `std::basic_streambuf` classes shows that they do not use atomic variables, so they may create race conditions when used for buffering. (On the other hand, libc++ `sync_with_stdio` effectively does nothing, so it doesn't matter if you call it.)

If you want extra performance regardless of locking, `sync_with_stdio(false)` is a good idea. However, after doing so, locking is necessary, along with `cerr.tie( nullptr )` if the locks are separate.

Comment: If you do want separate locking, I've [created](https://github.com/potswa/lock_ios) a library for it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful ;)

```
inline static void log(std::string const &format, ...) {
    static std::mutex locker;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(locker);

    va_list list;
    va_start(list, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format.c_str(), list);
    va_end(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
// Wrap a mutex around cerr so multiple threads don't overlap output
// USAGE:
//     LockedLog() << a << b << c;
// 
class LockedLog {
public:
    LockedLog() { m_mutex.lock(); }
    ~LockedLog() { *m_ostr << std::endl; m_mutex.unlock(); }

    template <class T>
    LockedLog &operator << (const T &msg)
    {
        *m_ostr << msg;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    static std::ostream *m_ostr;
    static std::mutex m_mutex;
};

std::mutex LockedLog::m_mutex;
std::ostream* LockedLog::m_ostr = &std::cerr;
```