# C++ threads why the cout statements are not getting printed even after fflush

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
void pause_thread(int n)
{
    if(n != 4)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(100));
        std::cout << "pause of " << 100 << " seconds ended\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Thread number " << n << " ended\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[6];                         // default-constructed threads
    std::setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    std::cout << "Spawning 5 threads...\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        //If the object is currently not joinable, it acquires the thread of execution represented by rhs (if any).
        //If it is joinable, terminate() is called. If it is joinable, terminate() is called.
        //rhs no longer represents any thread of execution
        threads[i] = std::move(std::thread(pause_thread, i));    // move-assign threads
    }
    std::thread& i = threads[4];
    threads[5] = std::move(threads[4]);
    std::cout << "Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        if(threads[i].joinable())
        {
            std::cout << "Thread " << i << " " << threads[i].get_id() << " ID joinable" << std::endl << std::flush;
            threads[i].join();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Thread " << i << " not joinable" << std::endl << std::flush;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "All threads joined!\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output I received:

```
Spawning 5 threads...  
Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:     
Thread 0 22476 ID joinable   
Thread number 4 ended  
.... no output for 100 seconds ..
pause of 100 seconds ended
Thread number 0 ended  
pause of 100 seconds ended 
Thread 1 28676 ID joinable    
pause of 100 seconds ended 
Thread number 2 ended       
Thread number 3 ended  
pause of 100 seconds ended   
Thread number 1 ended        
Thread 2 2336 ID joinable    
Thread 3 42236 ID joinable  
Thread 4 not joinable        
Thread 5 35940 ID joinable  
All threads joined!
```

How the **"Thread n xxxx ID joinable"**  statements are getting printed after **"Thread number n ended"**? I have even tried using set std::output as non buffered but the output was same?

Comment: what other output did you expect? I dont see the problem with what you got. First the threads print something and then you print something when you check if they are joinable and when you join them

Comment: You're not flushing the `cout` in `pause_thread`, so it could get printed like you see.

Comment: `std::cout` on its own is not thread safe afaik

Comment: I was expecting that all "Thread n xxxx ID joinable" should get printed first and if "Thread number n ended" then the thread n becomes non-joinable so "Thread n not joinable" should get printed as the thread n has already terminated

Comment: @idclev463035818 _`std::cout` on its own is not thread safe afaik_ AFAIK, `std::iostream` _is_ thread-safe. [SO: iostream thread safety, must cout and cerr be locked separately?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14637716/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff oh, I am still carrying some pre-C++11 beliefs with me. Thx for busting that one

Comment: Unrelated: You could rewrite `for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { if(threads[i].joinable()) ...` as `for(auto& th : threads) { if(th.joinable()) ...` to keep magic numbers like `6` out of it.

Comment: `main` (thread) stop at first loop `threads[0].join();` so you effectively doesn't wait at any thread (since they all have pass 100 second when `threads[0]` successfully joined.)

Comment: and as others said, ended thread is `joinable` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

Comment: Then why "Thread 4 not joinable" gets logged?

Comment: `<< std::endl << std::flush` is superfluous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Joinable" does not imply that the thread is still executing.

You first join thread #0.  This will take ~100 seconds.
During that time, thread #4 finishes since it doesn't sleep, and the other threads are sleeping.
If the threads happen to be scheduled differently, any of the "sleep threads" could be printing that they've ended here.

Once the wait for thread #0 is over, you start joining the other threads.
Some of these have finished executing before you join them and some haven't.
In this particular instance, none of them finished before the wait for thread #0 was over, but there is no guarantee of that happening.

And note that a line like

```
std::cout << "Thread number " << n << " ended\n";
```

is not atomic and characters from different threads can be interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

Because joinable does not mean what you think : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable

So any thread that is started is "joinable" it does not need to have finished running.